# controlbook.tex figure inclusion problem

Tags: floats

```
\begin{figure}\label{key}
\graphicspath{H:/NewFolder} 
\includegraphics[scale=1, bb= 50 50 210 265]{vanessa}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

I am writing a book. The text is compiling without any fault with the above command. No figure is generated. Please suggest.

Comment: Does it give any warning in the log? Also is it completely invisible or there is a box instead? It would be really helpful if you can put the whole example. I mean is it working if you only put this code inside an empty `article` document?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please give us a full MWE, showing your documentclass and the packages regarding figures. have you checked other images, have you checked without that options? `scale=1` and `\caption{}` can be omitted (at least for this very case here).

Answer (score 4):

Each directory in `\graphicspath` should be put into a set of curly braces and should end with the directory separator:

```
\graphicspath{{H:/NewFolder/}}
```

The command is documented in section ["4.5 Other commands in the `graphics` package"](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/graphics/grfguide.pdf).

Also the path can be directly specified in `\includegraphics`:

```
\includegraphics{H:/NewFolder/vanessa}
```

The use of option `bb` looks suspicious, but this depends on the unknown image and driver types.